# Is the multi-pet-families tag too similar to the compatibility tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tagging

**Tag wiki for** [multi-pet-families](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-pet-families)

> Regards concerns about households containing multiple pets of the same
> or different species and their interactions.

**Tag wiki for** [compatibility](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility)

> Questions about whether two or more animals might be compatible with
> each other, or even if the animal is compatible with the owner.

It seems to me like [multi-pet-families](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-pet-families) is a synonym for [compatibility](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility), am I right? What's the difference?

Note: I found the discussion from when the tag was made. [Usage and definition of Multi-Pet-Families tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/usage-and-definition-of-multi-pet-families-tag)

Answer (score 4):

I would read them as different.

[multi-pet-families](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-pet-families) is about dealing with problems and issues within the home as a result of having more than one pet.

[compatibility](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility) is about how two or more animals may get along (second animal may be people).

There may be some minor cross-over there, but not necessarily. For example, compatibility of fish species doesn't otherwise really reflect a multi-pet household situation the same way as having a doberman and a guinea pig might. For example, the two might be compatible (not likely ;p) but then the introduction of the guinea pig might bother the doberman causing him to urinate inappropriately. The species may be compatible, the problem is home specific and the situation may or may not apply to others.

Comment: I get it now, but I'm starting to think it's just not used quite like it's supposed to be. It really should only be used in questions where it's a question about multiple pets getting along it sounds like.